# Trouble with character device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm a little bit confused about character device driver. I wrote a simple character device driver and it works with strings and simple things. Now I have to implement it and modify the write function to receive an integer N.

Since I have to receive an integer I thought to modify the write function and instead of a char* buffer receive an int* number but when I try to map file_operations with "my_write" terminal gives me an error saying "incompatible array types".

My question is what I have to modify in order to receive an integer with the write function insted of a string

These are my functions:

```
static ssize_t my_write 
      (struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    int nc = 0;

    if (length > BUF_LEN)
        return BUF_LEN-length;

    nc = copy_from_user(msg,buf,length); 
    msg_ptr = msg;

    return length - nc;
}
```

Comment: "I thought to modify the write function" Nope, it doesn't work this way. Your fumction must be of a certain predefined type and you don't have any freedom in choosing it. If you expect the user to call `write` and pass an `int*`, you have to use a cast to convert your function parameter to `int*`, or copy from user to an `int` buffer (and make sure you have at least `sizeof(int)` bytes).

Comment: You receive characters through the driver. Whether you want to convert these characters to integers, floating point numbers, or mp3 songs doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you get this data character by character.

Comment: So if I understood I don't have to modify the function parameters but only the function algorithm. So I receive from the user a char * buffer and I convert it into an integer . Instead of assigning "msg" which is a char array to a pointer I convert msg into an integer. I'm correct?

Comment: You seem fixated on the *"char"* aspect.  The salient issue is that a "char" device is not a block device, i.e. transfers involving a fixed transfer size.  That means that a "char" device can transfer a variable number of "char" or bytes.  In fact you could replace *"char"* with "byte", and maybe things get clearer.  I.E. instead of read/write strings, the char driver handles (unsigned) byte arrays.  So you're not correct to *"convert msg into an integer"*.

Comment: Okay perfect! I was confused but now evrything works! thanks